# Lebesgue outer measure of image of an increasing function

Tags: real-analysis

Prove: If $f$ is an increasing function on $[a,b]$ and $E=\{x\in [a,b]| f'(x) \text{ exists}\}$. Then $m^{*}f(E)=\int_{E}f'(x)dx.$

$f$ has at most countably many points where the derivative doesn't exist, so we can prove the proposition on an open interval where the derivative exists everywhere. I know in general $m^{*}f(E)\leq \int_{E}|f'(x)|dx$ for any measurable function on $[a,b]$ and $E$ as defined above. I found a proof of this genral fact in Varberg's paper "on absolutely continuous functions". After checking the proof there, I don't see how we can achieve equality for an increasing function.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I figured out a proof. Hope this will be helpful to people who will see this post in the future.

Let $f=f_{c}+f_{s}$ where $f_{c}$ is the continuous part and $f_{s}$ is the discrete part. $f_{c}$ is increasing since $f$ is increasing. $f$ is continuous on $E$, therefore $f_{s}=0$ on $E$. $f_{s}=f-f_{c}\in BV([a,b])$, hence differentiable a.e. and $f_{s}'=0$ a.e. $f_{c}'=f'$ a.e. Now $f_{c}$ is continuous, $f_{c}'$ exists for all but at most countable set of points and $f_{c}'$ is integrable, by a similar proof as that of Banach-Zaretsky theorem, $f_{c}'$ is absolutely continuous.
$m^{*}f(E)=m^{*}f_{c}(E)=m^{*}f_{c}([a,b])=f_{c}(b)-f_{c}(a)=\int_{a}^{b}f_{c}'=\int_{a}^{b}f'$.